# slick slide slider counter issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I am using slick slider in my web page. I am using multiple slider in one page. every slider is working fine. I also added a slider counter bottom of the slider. but it seems if I go to the next slide of a slider the counter is taking effect on every slide. at the same time. for e.g If I go to next slide on first slide it shows 2 out of 4 in every slider instead of only the first slider.

Here is the jquery I am using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $status = $('.slider_tag span');
    var $slickElement = $('.modules');

    $slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
        var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
        $status.text(i + ' of ' + slick.slideCount);
    });


    $slickElement.slick({
        slide: '.module_wrap',
        autoplay: false,
        dots: false,
        arrows: true,
    });
});
```

Here is the html

```
<div class="modules col-md-5">
    <div class="module_wrap">
        <div class="mods">
            <a href="single.html"><img src="images/slide.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="module_wrap">
        <div class="mods">
            <a href="single.html"><img src="images/slide.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="module_wrap">
        <div class="mods">
            <a href="single.html"><img src="images/slide.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="module_wrap">
        <div class="mods">
            <a href="single.html"><img src="images/slide.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider_tag">Slide <span> </span></div>

</div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rony747/mx7nLpdt/)

Comment: Can you add a Jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle added. thanks

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small change in your fiddle was good enough to fix the issue. Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mx7nLpdt/1/)

The issue was with this line of code

```
 $status.text(i + ' of ' + slick.slideCount);
```

where `$status` is

```
  var $status = $('.slider_tag span');
```

That means all the span tags, and you were updating all the span tags for any of the carousel next slide event. So only thing is change this line of code to

```
$(this).find('.slider_tag span').text(i + ' of ' + slick.slideCount);
```

And it must be fixed.